# VMware Tools cannot find openSUSE kernel sources

Tags: vmware-workstation, opensuse

I inherited an openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) virtual machine from previous developer and exported disk files from Virtualbox VDI to VMWare's VMDK.

The virtual machine works and VMware Tools are installed, but I can't complete configuration process because the configurator can't find kernel sources. Display auto resolution doesn't work.

But kernel sources are installed! YaST displays them as installed and /usr/src directory contains some linux subdirectories:

- linux
- linux-obj
- linux-2.6.25.5-1.1
- linux-2.6.25.5-1.1-obj
- linux-3.16.6-2
- linux-3.16.6-2-obj
- linux-3.16.7-21
- linux-3.16.7-21-obj

Installed kernel version is 3.16.6-2-default

VMWare Tools configurator complains

```
Searching for a valid kernel header path...
The path "" is not valid.
Would you like to change it? [yes] 

What is the location of the directory of C header files that match your running kernel? /usr/src/linux

The path "/usr/src/linux" is not valid.
Would you like to change it? [yes]
```

If I only knew which files the configurator tries to search for, I could try to find them by myself.

VMWare Workstation 7.0.1.

Please help me to install these tools.

Comment: Maybe these commands solve the problem:  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Or see this thread , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805697/installing-vmware-tools-not-recognizing-path-to-3-8-0-19-generic-kernel-files

Answer (score 1):

kernel headers in SUSE are a part of the kernel source package or kernel development pattern. To be able to utilize headers you generally need C tools and base development tools installed as well. I'd recommend running the following command as root or with sudo to install everything you'll need:

```
zypper install -t pattern devel_basis devel_C_C++ devel_kernel
```

I'd also recommend rebooting after the install completes.

Comment: Looking at the file system how could I check whether kernel source package is installed? Which files must be present in a folder?

Comment: To check if a package is installed I would recommend using the package tools. For SUSE that would be: `zypper se kernel-source` or `rpm -q kernel-source`. However, the files that come from the kernel-source package (at least for SUSE) are in the directory `/usr/src/linux-<kernel version>`

Comment: @Paul If I was able to answer your question would you mind setting my answer as your solution so that I can get the reputation points for it? Thanks!

Comment: @Paul could you add the full output to a pastebin.com link so that I can see it a little easier? Make sure to include the full command that was run as well. Thanks!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/N0xaHMQC. TopHat, before to install something I would like to check if it is already installed to avoid unnecessary downloads and may be corruption of well-tuned package.

Comment: According to zypper the package is installed. I would like to know not whether it is installed, but whether it contains files required by VMWare tools configurator. In order to be sure I would like to know exact files it is looking for.

Comment: @Paul have you customized your repositories? On my 13.2 with standard repos enabled I don't have this package conflict. I advised the method you can use to check if it's already installed, also if it's already installed it will tell you and abort the install. You'd have to add a force flag for it to install anyways.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I inherited the virtual machine from previous developer.

Comment: @Paul https://en.opensuse.org/Package_repositories#Official_Repositories here's the link for the official openSUSE repositories. The one's you want and are default are: oss, non-oss, update, update non-oss. You can list repositories with `zypper lr` and enable them with `zypper mr -e <repo id>`

Comment: @Paul I understand your hesitance to change the system if you are unfamiliar with it and its environment. I'd recommend making a backup before making any changes such as package installs and modifying repositories just in case.